# Scraping ajax content getting empty elements

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, web-scraping, android-webview

I wanted to get the origin/destination list of an [airline website](https://www.cebupacificair.com/). I could see the places on the source file but they are on json format instead of a list element or something but when you do inspect element, you would see an unordered list of the places so I assume it is parsed from the json data dynamically.

I tried using webview to get the source of the site after loading hoping that I would get a complete data but the source contains elements like empty div tags.

I'm not familiar with AJAX but how would I scrape this data? I have one solution and that is to get the json data and parse it myself but I would like to know if there are other methods to get this dynamic data.

My current code:

```
 webView.addJavascriptInterface(cpInterface, "HtmlViewer");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
            }
        });

 webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
 webView.loadUrl("https://www.cebupacificair.com/");

public class CPInterface {

        public String html;
        private WebView webView;

        public CPInterface(WebView webView) {
            this.webView = webView;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showHTML(final String html) {
            this.html = html;
        }
    }
```

Comment: My first thought: If what you could get seems like JSON, why not use it? What better data format are you hoping for?

Comment: The json data is quite complex but if i could get the unordered list element of the places, it would be easier and ready to use. It's one of my solutions anyway, im just hoping to find a way to get the list..